# How to get R gtsummary package tbl_strata() function to not print zeros with (NA%) for a variable that has entirely missing values for one strata?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to display data stratified by shop type (Auto or Beauty). Using the gtsummary package tbl_strata() function works well for all of the variables except for one variable that is only a beauty shop variable, so it is missing entirely for the auto shops. For that one problem variable, the output displays zeros with (NA%) on the top line, which I do not want. I show a small reproducible example below with just a few values of the problem variable to show the issue.

Here is my rmarkdown code:

```
library(gtsummary) # for tbl_strata() for more customizable demographics table
library(gt) # for making nice looking display tables
library(tidyverse) # for data wrangling

test.tb <- tibble(
  auto_or_beauty = c("Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Auto", "Auto", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty"),
  specific_beauty_shop_type = c("Hair only", "Hair and nails", "Hair only", "Hair and nails", "Hair only", NA, NA, "Hair and nails", "Hair only", "Hair only"),
  intervention_group = c("Delayed", "Delayed", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Immediate", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Immediate")
)

test.tb %>%
  # create a tbl_summary() table within each level of auto_or_beauty
  tbl_strata(
    strata = auto_or_beauty,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(by = intervention_group)) %>%
  as_gt()
```

And here is the output:
[image: tbl_strata() output table]

I do not want the top line under Auto with 0 (NA%) 0 (NA%) for the specific_beauty_shop_type variable. Also, I would prefer that the number of unknown variables was displayed at the bottom after the levels of the variable, instead of at the top: how would I do that? (For all of my other variables, Unknown defaults to the bottom.)

Thanks! I am new to learning gtsummary, and I appreciate how flexible it is for allowing me to specify exactly how I want the table (it's much more flexible than the previous package I used). However, I am struggling with what to do when I have a strange case like this.

**EDIT:** My actual data table also has other variables and p-values with separate footnotes for each p-value. Can I have it not calculate a p-value for Auto shops for the specific_beauty_shop_type variable, and put no footnote there either? Here is code for an updated example:

```
test.tb <- tibble(
  auto_or_beauty = c("Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Auto", "Auto", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty"),
  specific_beauty_shop_type = c("Hair only", "Hair and nails", "Hair only", "Hair and nails", "Hair only", NA, NA, "Hair and nails", "Hair only", "Hair only"),
  intervention_group = c("Delayed", "Delayed", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Immediate", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Immediate"),
  home_business = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
)

 
test.tb %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = auto_or_beauty,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = intervention_group) %>% 
      add_p() %>% 
      separate_p_footnotes()
  )
```

[image: Revised code output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to fix both issues would be to use `modify_table_body`. First, to get rid of the `0 (NA%)` cells you could set the `stat` columns for Auto to `NA` for the `"label"` row. Second, to get the right order you could convert `specific_beauty_shop_type` to a factor. However, this will add `0 (NA%)` cells for the non-missing categories which we could get rid off by replacing with `NA` for the `"level"` rows.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

test.tb %>%
  mutate(specific_beauty_shop_type = factor(specific_beauty_shop_type)) |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = auto_or_beauty,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = intervention_group)
  ) |>
  modify_table_body(
    fun = ~ .x |>
      mutate(
        across(
          c(stat_1_1, stat_2_1),
          ~ if_else(row_type %in% c("label", "level"), NA, .x)
        )
      )
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Based on your comment you could restrict the replacement of the `NA`s by conditioning on the `variable` in the `if_else`:

```
test.tb <- tibble(
  auto_or_beauty = c("Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Auto", "Auto", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty"),
  specific_beauty_shop_type = c("Hair only", "Hair and nails", "Hair only", "Hair and nails", "Hair only", NA, NA, "Hair and nails", "Hair only", "Hair only"),
  intervention_group = c("Delayed", "Delayed", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Immediate", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Delayed", "Immediate", "Immediate"),
  home_business = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
)

test.tb %>%
  mutate(specific_beauty_shop_type = factor(specific_beauty_shop_type)) |>
  tbl_strata(
    strata = auto_or_beauty,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = intervention_group)
  ) |>
  modify_table_body(
    fun = ~ .x |>
      mutate(
        across(
          c(stat_1_1, stat_2_1),
          ~ if_else(
            variable %in% "specific_beauty_shop_type" &
              row_type %in% c("label", "level"), NA, .x
          )
        )
      )
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT 2** Now it's becoming a mess. I think for next add-on question we need another question.(; Unfortunately there is no easy fix for this case but it could be achieved by writing a custom test function to account for the "error" cases using `tryCatch`. Doing so we can capture the error and return a list of `NA`s instead.

```
my_fisher <- function(x, y) {
  tryCatch(
    fisher.test(x, y),
    error = function(e) {
      res <- list(
        p.value = NA,
        method = NA
      )
      class(res) <- "htest"
      res
    }
  )
}

fisher_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  data <- data[c(variable, by)] %>% dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.))
  my_fisher(data[[variable]], factor(data[[by]])) |>
    broom::tidy()
}

tbl <- test.tb %>%
  mutate(specific_beauty_shop_type = factor(specific_beauty_shop_type)) |>
  tbl_strata(
    strata = auto_or_beauty,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = intervention_group) %>%
        add_p(everything() ~ "fisher_test") %>%
        separate_p_footnotes()
  ) |>
  modify_table_body(
    fun = ~ .x |>
      mutate(
        across(
          c(stat_1_1, stat_2_1),
          ~ if_else(
            variable %in% "specific_beauty_shop_type" &
              row_type %in% c("label", "level"), NA, .x
          )
        )
      )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, I have other variables in my actual table (that I hadn't included in the example to keep it minimal), and this gets rid of values for those other variables that should be there. For example, if you add a variable to test.tb of home_business = factor(c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No","No","No","No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), then the code above also removes the auto numbers from the home_business variable. Is there a way to restrict the modify_table_body() function to only apply it to the variable specific_beauty_shop_type?

Comment: See my edit. That was indeed an easy fix. (:

Comment: Thanks! One more question for you if you have the patience. My actual data table has p-values with separate footnotes for each p-value (so add %>% add_p() %>% separate_p_footnotes() after tbl_summary(by = intervention_group) in the example). However, there's an error calculating the p-value for specific_beauty_shop_type and nothing appears except a footnote for Auto. I don't want to calculate a p-value for specific_beauty_shop_type for Auto (it doesn't make sense), and I don't want it to display a footnote for it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See my edit 2. At least for the case of your extended example data we now end up with an empty p-value column for "Auto".

Answer (score 1):

This is more a manual approach but since you have a fringe case here it might be useful. you can directly access the data and change it with mutate statements. Then I arranged the data with arrange.

```
library(gtsummary) # for tbl_strata() for more customizable demographics table
library(gt) # for making nice looking display tables
library(tidyverse) # for data wrangling


t1 <- test.tb %>%
  # create a tbl_summary() table within each level of auto_or_beauty
  tbl_strata(
    strata = auto_or_beauty,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(by = intervention_group)) %>%
  as_gt()



t1$`_data`$stat_1_1 <- ifelse(t1$`_data`$stat_1_1 == "0 (NA%)", NA,t1$`_data`$stat_1_1  )

t1$`_data`$stat_2_1 <- ifelse(t1$`_data`$stat_2_1 == "0 (NA%)", NA,t1$`_data`$stat_2_1  )

t1$`_data` <- arrange(t1$`_data`, row_type)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am implementing Stefan's answer above, but it's helpful for me to know how to edit the data more manually like this if I have weird cases in the future.